# Read or Import a Python file and only execute certain lines

Tags: python

I'm working on some test automation.  I am developing a framework to execute the tests.  Specifically I am writing the framework in Python and using Selenium.  The framework will be independent of the test files (also Python).  I have figured out how to read the file into a list and pull out the test steps (I am trying to include tracking and reporting as well), however I can't figure out how to execute the test steps.  Is there a way to have Python execute code that is stored in a list?

Below is an example of what I am doing, I would like to execute everything between Start and End.

```
testContent = [line.strip() for line in open(tests)]

for position, i in enumerate(testContent):
    if "Start Test" in i:
        testStart = position
    elif "End Test" in i:
        testEnd = position
    else:
        break
```

Sample Test:

```
# !/use/bin/env_python

# Test Case

from framework import navigation
from framework import test


def main():
# platform = "web"
# browser = "Firefox"
# Start Test
navigation.GoTo.menu(driver, "Local News")
navigation.GoTo.navbar(driver, "Education")
test.imagesloaded(driver)
# test.allLinksValid()

# End Test
```

Comment: Use functions...

Comment: What does a few lines of your tests look like? because i think that you MIGHT be asking an XY problem here...

Comment: have you checked out eval() and exec()? Of course I am assuming that the tests are written in python. If you're creating your own testing language your task is much larger

Comment: @cwlovell13 np - good luck

Comment: No, no, no! Eval and exec are not the right way to do this! Please look at nose and unittest and other testing frameworks, as well as Python's `inspect` module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But, this is exactly what `unittest.loadTestsFromModule` is for.

Just add `__init__.py` to your test directory and read the docs: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/unittest.html

Comment: YES, exactly this. There is no reason to reinvent the wheel here. Lots of good options for unit testing in Python, including with Selenium and friends.

Comment: I will research nose, thanks!  It is just such a pain finding anything for learning all of this, learning Python and Friends as I go.